# Rendering Data on angular html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular8

I am working on a angular application. I have a json in my assests folder and I am loading json data into component as follows:

```
import data from './../.assets/data.json';
```

after  this I am assigning this data to a array as follows in ngOnInit;

```
array1 = data;
```

Now I am calling one method in ngOnInit which takes this array and some data coming from rabbitmq and do some calculation and gives me final resultant array "resultArray". My code is working fine but the problem is I want to render data in my html on loading with array1(data coming from json). Once page is loaded I want to see json data already on page. But when I send my data to my component from rabbit mq(My component gets data when rabbit mq sends it and I do some operation and show it on html) I want my html to render data from "resultArray". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use in template some variable (for example, `displayedArray`)
2. on init of your component set to this variable `data`
3. after loading array from DB make calculations and save result to `displayedArray`, angular update view according to data inside of `displayedArray`;

   ```
   @Component({
      template: "{{ displayedArray | json }}"
   }) 
   class MyMagicComponent {
      displayedArray: Array<any>;

      constructor(private _myMagicDBService: DBService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.displayedArray = data;
        this._myMagicDBService.getMyData().subscribe(res => {
          this.displayedArray = makeSomeMagicWithDataFromDB(res);
        })
      }
   }
   ```